# Could you tell me "consult your advice" is correct or not?

Tags: word-usage

I see a lot of articles or pubic advertisements saying “consult your doctor/lawyer” instead of “consult somebody’s advice”.

Does it mean “consult somebody’s advice/opinions” is a wrong expression, or it is not a natural expression even if it is grammatically correct?

For example: I would consult your advice for this matter. This sentence is right?

I googled this phrase, the only reliable result shows it was in a 1947 document. It is eliminated by the modern culture?

Comment: You **consult** your lawyer/doctor. You **ask for** their advice/opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Consult someone's advice*" is tautological and stilted, and is a locution people don't usually say. The reason is that the verb consult in this sense means "*seek information or advice from*" (Lexico/Google), and you don't **seek advice from someone's advice.* You consult a person, a sentient being.

Note that there is another sense of the verb. You can consult inanimate objects, usually a reference or a book, for information. It is a slightly different usage than the one mentioned above. It means to refer to a book for information.

For idiomatic expressions, Weather Vane's offered a good one: You *ask for* people's advice. In a lot of contexts you can safely use "**heed** their advice" or "**follow** their advice".

Comment: Thank you Eddie.